# How can I import this entry answer into a text after

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Okay so I have this sign up form and there is a part where you have to enter your name, I want that name answer to be taken to the page after.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("150x50+680+350")

def FormSubmission():
    global button_start
    button_start.place_forget()
    l1.place_forget()
    root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
    frame = tk.Frame(root)
    tk.Label(frame, text="First Name:").grid(row=0)
    name = entry1 = tk.Entry(frame) # I want the name written here to be taken from here to the welcome text.
    entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    tk.Label(frame, text="Last Name:").grid(row=1)
    e2 = tk.Entry(frame)
    e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
    tk.Label(frame, text="Email:").grid(row=2)
    e3 = tk.Entry(frame)
    e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
    tk.Label(frame, text="Date of Birth:").grid(row=3)
    e4 = tk.Entry(frame)
    e4.grid(row=3, column=1)
    frame.pack(anchor='center', expand=True)
    button_next = tk.Button(frame, text = "Next", height = 2, width = 7, command =lambda: MainPage(frame))
    button_next.grid(row=4, column=1)

def MainPage(frame):
    global FormSubmission
    frame.pack_forget()
    root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
    l1.place(x = 500, y = 10)
    button_start.place_forget()

l1 = tk.Label(root, text="Welcome," , font=("Arial", 44)) #As you can see here in this line I want the entry 1 name here after welcome and the comma
button_start = tk.Button(root, text="Start", height=3, width=20, command = FormSubmission)
button_start.place(x = 0, y = 10)
button_exit = tk.Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
button_exit.place(x=1506, y=0)

root.mainloop()
```

What I want to do is take the entry 1 answer and put it in the welcome text. There is an indicator on the lines I'm talking about.

Comment: You can pass `entry1.get()` to `MainPage(frame, ...)`, then use `l1.config(text=...)` with the passed value.

Comment: @acw1668 how would that look like in actual code? can you write the small part in an actual code paragraph and send it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to provide text from your widget entry1

1. in function FormSubmission():where you are defining your button you should pass the text you want to show in your label

   ```
   button_next = tk.Button(frame, text = "Next", height = 2, width = 7, command =lambda: MainPage(frame, entry1.get()))
   ```
2. in funtion MainPage(frame):you should set text to your label:

   ```
    def MainPage(frame, entry1):
         global FormSubmission
         frame.pack_forget()
         root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
         l1.place(x = 500, y = 10)
         button_start.place_forget()
         l1.config(text="Welcome," + entry1) #<-------
   ```

[image]

[image]